Is the "real world" actually real?
When Morpheus frees Neo, Neo is taken to what is referred to as the real world. This world is described as real, as opposed to The Matrix, which is an unreal simulation.
According to canon, is there anything to indicate that this "real world" may actually have the same nature as The Matrix, another level of a simulation?

Its turtles all the way down…

Not sure if it's speculation but I'm practically sure some people talked about how it's just all layers of simulation on top of each others or something. There's a question/answer somewhere on the site about it.

Maybe that should have been the forth film.

How do you know that our world is actually real and not a simulation?

Duplicate of Other than Neo Stopping the Machine Weapons, Are There Clues the Real World is Another Matrix?.

@IloneSP I do not, I actually like Advaita Vedanta which proposes that this world is indeed a dream.

That's just what I don't like about this kind of movie, or book. There is no clear ending. If there is to be a sequel, fine, but eventually there should be a final answer.

@IloneSP It’s really annoying how a movie put this nonsense in so many people’s heads.

@FlaStorm32 If ever there was a Big Question about life, the Universe and everything, this is it. Hence, there is a final answer: 42. And a clear ending by the same token.

@suchiuomizu uhm this has been around since the Vedic civilization and the vedas, it did not come from that movie alone.
